# Passing PHP session from one page to another

Tags: php, session

to be more relevant, i edit my question accordingly, i got ReqData.php and SendData.php where the first has input for id in a form using post the purpose of my code is to send the id from ReqData to SendData and decrypt the encrypted id which is done is ReqData using following code

```
function public_encrypt($plaintext){
$fp=fopen("mykey.pub","r");
$pub_key=fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);
openssl_get_publickey($pub_key);
openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext,$crypttext, $pub_key );
return(base64_encode($crypttext));
}


$_SESSION['caesar'] = public_encrypt($_POST["inc"]);
```

and then go to SendData to be decrypted using

```
function private_decrypt($encryptedext){
$fp=fopen("mykey.pem","r");
$priv_key=fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);
$private_key = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedext), $decrypted, $private_key);
return $decrypted; 
}

$encryp = $_SESSION['caesar'];
echo $encryp."<br/>";
$demo = private_decrypt($encryp);
echo "<br/>";
echo $demo;
```

my problem is it can detect the session but it's not decrypting, for ur info, i'm using rsa encryption

update: i var_dump($demo), it give me string(0) "", it supposed to be value i type in the id input box

Comment: what does `var_dump($_SESSION);` produce? Is error reporting on? Refer to @ICanHasCheezburger comment too

Comment: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work if you have `session_start();` set. Check if you are unsetting the session somewhere after setting or destroying it.

Comment: At the begining of SendData.php, do a var_dump($_SESSION); and show us what you have

Comment: i got this array(2) { ["caesar"]=> string(344)

Comment: and follow by hundred of random alphabets and numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need this

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Comment: "i have already included session start at the first line of both of my php page" - although, I agree with your answer.

Comment: @samitha user has already mentioned that user has put session start in both the pages..

Comment: try to see what is produced by var_dump($_SESSION['think']); on second page..?